# React native app doesn't receive image from Espresso-Intent

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I'm writing Espresso tests to run on my React Native app. I'm using `Espresso-Intents` to simulate the user taking a picture, with the following code:

```
public void takePicture() {
    Instrumentation.ActivityResult result = createImageCaptureActivityResultStub();

    intending(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)).respondWith(result);
    clickText("Camera");
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}

private Instrumentation.ActivityResult createImageCaptureActivityResultStub() {
    // Put the drawable in a bundle.
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("data", getBitmapFromURL("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/the-feed-your-pets-community/images/6/69/Banana.png/revision/latest?cb=20180527162222"));

    // Create the Intent that will include the bundle.
    Intent resultData = new Intent();
    resultData.putExtras(bundle);

    // Create the ActivityResult with the Intent.
    return new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
}
```

When running, the camera intent is successfully stubbed, but the view which should display the photo is stuck in its loading state.

In debugging, I have discovered that `getBitmapFromURL` is not the problem, because `bundle` contains the correct image.

Could anyone suggest where the problem may lie, or how best to debug further?

Comment: use putSerializable instead of putParcelable.

Comment: @ViralPatel Hi, using `putSerializable` I get `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'android.graphics.Bitmap', required: 'java.io.Serializable'`. If I pass simply the URL as a string I get the same result as the original problem. Do I need to manipulate the bitmap before passing it to `putSerializable`?

Comment: Could you show us the `onActivityResult` and `startActivityForResult` code fragments?

Comment: @ahasbini It's a react native project, so I don't have those...

Comment: Apologies I missed that out when started thinking about the implementations in Java. Could you instead share what you used in React native to get an image from camera? Are you using the `react-native-image-picker`?

Comment: @ahasbini Yes, I'm using `react-native-camera` and `react-native-image-picker`; the user has the option to either take a picture or choose one. Stubbing either will be sufficient for testing.